# Elasticsearch tokenizer with Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am not sure if I did it right, please advise.

I have created an index called users in the Elasticsearch with the ngram tokenizer.

```
PUT users
{
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "es_analyzer":{
            "tokenizer":"es_token"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer":{
          "es_token": {
            "type": "ngram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 1,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
            "digit"
              ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I want to use Java to query the users index in Elasticsearch and here is my code. I used WildcardQueryBuilder, to query the index, is it right to do that? Since I have a tokenizer in my index. how can I make use of the tokenizer in Java?

```
public List<UserES> search(String keywords) {           
       List<UserES> users = new ArrayList<>();

       Gson gson = new Gson();
       SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
       BoolQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
       qb.should(new WildcardQueryBuilder("role", "*" + keywords + "*"));
       qb.should(new WildcardQueryBuilder("name", "*" + keywords + "*"));
       sourceBuilder.query(qb);
         
       SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("users").source(sourceBuilder);

       try {
           SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
           
           SearchHit[] searchHit = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
           for (SearchHit hit : searchHit) {
               UserES a = gson.fromJson(hit.getSourceAsString(), UserES.class);
               a.setId(hit.getId());
               users.add(a);
            }
           
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return users;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define [analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#text-params) in your [index mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/explicit-mapping.html). Though, n-grams consume a lot of resources on indexing and are tricky to set up right so you might want to try a [wilcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type) field instead.

Comment: I just tried wildcard field, I think case sensitive is not supported.